# TYPO3 Solr Search: limit custom index queue to core for a specific language

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I've been fiddling around with the ext_solr extension (3.1.1) for TYPO3 (7.6.4) for a while. My configuration uses two Solr cores for two different languages (English and German); this works perfectly fine for normal pages. In the TS constants, the cores are configured like this:

```
plugin.tx_solr.solr.path = /core_en/
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
plugin.tx_solr.solr.path = /core_de/
[end]
```

To get English and German results from the database separately, I created two different MySQL views that give me the correct results. I then proceed to set up indexing each of these views, like so:

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue {
[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
myindex = 1
myindex {
  table = my_view
  fields {
    abstract = abstract
    title = title
    tstamp = tstamp
    content = SOLR_CONTENT
    content {
      field = bodytext
    }
    url = TEXT
    url {
      typolink.parameter = 17
      typolink.additionalParams = &... [URL works correctly]
      typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
      typolink.returnLast = url
    }
  }
}
[end]
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
myindex_de = 1
myindex {
  table = my_view_de

  fields {
    abstract = abstract
    title = title
    tstamp = tstamp
    content = SOLR_CONTENT
    content {
      field = bodytext
    }
    url = TEXT
    url {
      typolink.parameter = 17
      typolink.additionalParams = &...
      typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
      typolink.returnLast = url
    }
  }
}
[end]
}
```

However, both language versions end up in both cores. Anything I could do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not working. From the docs: "Note that conditions cannot be used inside of curly brackets."
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Index.html

You need to wrap the TypoScript from the root level up and make the first levels "plugin.tx_solr. ..." redundant.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the configuration according to your answer, but now the Index Queue Initialization only offers me the English version (myindex), but not the German one (myindex_de). Any other ideas?

Comment: @SaschaKersken: See my answer above, you have still a typo in your TypoScript

Answer (score 0):

First of all: As mentioned, there is the rule for TypoScript conditions:

```
Note that conditions cannot be used inside of curly brackets.
```

So you have to change it.

Secondly, you have a typo in your code:

```
myindex_de = 1
myindex {
  table = my_view_de

  fields {
    abstract = abstract
    title = title
    tstamp = tstamp
    content = SOLR_CONTENT
    content {
      field = bodytext
    }
    url = TEXT
    url {
      typolink.parameter = 17
      typolink.additionalParams = &...
      typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
      typolink.returnLast = url
    }
  }
}
```

2nd row: it should be **myindex_de** too.

**Generally** I would suggest you a different solution:

1: Slightly different solution:

You referencing the same fields as I see by both myindex and myindex_de. So if the only difference the language it make sense to prepare it as **sys_language_uid** in your view.

2: The always working, "ultimate" solution:

If you have a very special case to handle, you can use PHP code to override an Indexer and make your own. This is a better approach, because you can make a lot more inside the indexer as just in a view. Like:

- FE user rights.
- Language differences
- It is used as a separated Scheduler task and you can give additional
  properties as settings to it.

I used both way already and it is true, that with a view you can build quick and easier a "one-line" variant from a complex data structure. 
However in an Indexer class you have the complete freedom to make data cleaning / data manipulation before you build your content together.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to give it a try right now. As for the typo you mentioned: it's not in the real code but happened when I anonymized and simplified the real code to post it here.